# I wrote a regex inside of a python script to analyse xml files but sadly its not working

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-2.x

I wrote a script to gather information out of an XML file. Inside, there are ENTITY's defined and I need a RegEx to get the value out of it.

```
<!ENTITY ABC         "123"> 
<!ENTITY BCD         "234"> 
<!ENTITY CDE         "345">
```

First, i open up the xml file and save the contents inside of a variable.

```
xml = open("file.xml", "r")
lines = xml.readlines()
```

Then I got a for loop:

```
result = "ABC"
var_search_result_list = []

var_searcher = "ENTITY\s" + result + '.*"[^"]*"\>'

for line in lines:
    var_search_result = re.match(var_searcher, line)

    if var_search_result != None:
        var_search_result_list += list(var_search_result.groups())

print(var_search_result_list)
```

I really want to have the value **123** inside of my *var_search_result_list* list. Instead, I get an empty list every time I use this. Has anybody got a solution?

Thanks in Advance - Toki

Comment: do u know about `xmltodict` ?

Comment: cant use any community modules or python 3.x at this project

Comment: share the xml and explain what are the attributes / elements you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in the code.

- You are using `re.match` which has to match from the start of the string.
  Your pattern is `ENTITY\sABC.*"([^"]*)"\>` which does not match from
  the start of the given example strings.
- If you want to add **123** only, you have to use a capture group, and add it using `var_search_result.group(1)` to the result list using append

For example:

```
import re

xml = open("file.xml", "r")
lines = xml.readlines()

result = "ABC"
var_search_result_list = []
var_searcher = "ENTITY\s" + result + '.*"([^"]*)"\>'
print(var_searcher)
for line in lines:
    var_search_result = re.search(var_searcher, line)
    if var_search_result:
        var_search_result_list.append(var_search_result.group(1))
print(var_search_result_list)
```

Output

```
['123']
```

A bit more precise pattern could be

```
<!ENTITY\sABC\s+"([^"]*)"\>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7jHPQg/1)